# Dynamically Get a Variable from HTML in Flash/AS3

Tags: html, actionscript-3, actionscript, drop-down-menu, flashvars

I have a case where I have a "drop-down box" in an HTML webpage with some JQuery calculations, looks something like this:

```
<select style="width: 190px;" class="calc" name="os2" id="os2" type="text">
<option value="Front" data-whatever="2">Front </option>
<option value="Front and Back" data-whatever="2.9">Front and Back </option>
</select>
```

What I'm trying to do is have this Flash ActionScript 3 Application (embedded on the same HTML page) grab a variable from the drop-down box. Now, using FlashVars is fine, except it doesn't account for when the selection is changed (obviously), but...

**Is there a way to reload the variable into Flash real-time when the user changes the drop-down box selection?**

Any light on this would be terrific, thanks a lot!

Comment: ExternalInterface is the way to go. To add to Marty's answer: You'll want to expose a method from Flash to JS using `ExternalInterface.addCallback()`. In JS, you'll want to listen for changes to the combo-box item; when one is detected, call the exposed function of your Flash object to tell it what the new value is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ExternalInterface`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to communicate between Flash and JavaScript.

This article seems to cover exactly what you want to do:
[Bi-Directional Actionscript/Javascript Communication in AS3](http://www.viget.com/inspire/bi-directional-actionscript-javascript-communication/)

> Bi-directional Actionscript/Javascript communication is something that has been out for a while, but some Flash designers/developers still are saying, "I didn't know you could do that."
>
> Well you can! And with just a little bit of code.

Comment: Terrific, exactly what I was looking for!